# How to rectify deployment error in Tomcat7 using maven?

Tags: maven, tomcat7, maven-cargo

I was using Tomcat 7 and JDK 7 in my development. when I am executing this maven goal `clean package cargo:redeploy` in Juno Eclipse, it show this error. Hope to see some clue from you.

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR : 
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:
javac: -endorseddirs requires an argument
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
use -help for a list of possible options

[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.717s
[INFO] Finished at: Sun Oct 28 09:25:37 MYT 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/149M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.3.2:compile (default-compile) on project Web2: Compilation failure
[ERROR] Failure executing javac, but could not parse the error:
[ERROR] javac: -endorseddirs requires an argument
[ERROR] Usage: javac <options> <source files>
[ERROR] use -help for a list of possible options
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoFailureException
```

This is my pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.huahsin68.web2</groupId>
  <artifactId>Web2</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>Web2 Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <finalName>Web2</finalName>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.cargo</groupId>
            <artifactId>cargo-maven2-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <container>
                    <containerId>tomcat7x</containerId>
                    <type>remote</type>
                </container>
                <configuration>
                    <type>runtime</type>
                    <properties>
                        <cargo.remote.username>${tomcat.username}</cargo.remote.username>
                        <cargo.remote.password>${tomcat.password}</cargo.remote.password>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using this configuration for the maven compiler plugin:

```
<compilerArguments>
  <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
</compilerArguments>
```

But it seems like you do not set the variable `${endorsed.dir}` anywhere. So Maven adds an empty `-endorseddirs` parameter to the java command line.

So you should either remove the `compilerArguments` entry from the plugin configuration or set the variable correctly.